# how to fix visual studio warning

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, warnings

i have made a app in visual studio 2010 ultimate the problem i am facing is when i publish my app then it is genrating some warning which is this

```
Warning 1   One of the following items 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)
, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1' is required by 'SQL Server 2008 Express',
 but none were included.    WindowsFormsApplication1
```

i know there is some problem which will i face as i seen my app it is working fine but some feature related to sql server it is not working. how can i fix this warning? i have gone through MSDN but there is no solution i got, i have unistalled visual studio and reinstalled it but the same problem i am facing

Comment: Click the Prerequisites button in Publish tab and tell us what items are checked.  If you unticked a framework selection then you need to explain why you did that.  And do your customer a favor and give your project a real name.

Comment: Prerequisites where it is? i have an english version instlled. soory i am newbie to visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695) page;

### Instructions

Step 1: Download and install [`Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120550).

Step 2: Download and install [`Windows Installer 4.5`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=123422).

Step 3: Download SQL Server 2008 Express by clicking the appropriate link later on this page. To start the installation immediately, click `Run`. To install SQL Server Express at a later time, click `Save`.

You need to download first .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 before using SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: sir i am using visual studio i want that from the menu i click new service based database. i dont want to create table from going to sql server. by your link sql server express can i get feature to make table from the visual studio and then adding new service based database?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server 2008 express, (doesn't matter you use directly or not) you need to install .net framework 3.5 sp1. Please install and see if this problem solved or not.

Comment: sir it is of 2.8 MB it is really or i have to install 100s of mbs?
and in my visual studio pack i have 3.5 sp1 installed

Comment: and i have installed sql server 2008 R2 when installing visual studio 2010 ultimate so. why it is asking to install express edition?

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio go to Project.. Properties.. Publish. Click on Prerequisites. If you have installed the Client Profile then turn on the Client Profile and turn off then one that is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check on your Customer's PC if .net-Framework is in the required Version installed.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785

Probably Service Pack 1 is missing...

Comment: service pack 1 is missing?? which service pack?

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
Mostly is only the 3.5 installed but the Service Pack 1 is missing...

Comment: in my setup i have installed 3.5 sp1 also.